# Can someone explain what is going on with `push` here?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It feels like `push` is behaving funny. Rather than just push to 1 index inside the `forEach`, it seems to be pushing to all 3 indexes. Am I missing something obvious?

```js
 let arrayToReduce = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
    let reduced = arrayToReduce.reduce((arr, inner) => {
      const copied = arr.slice()
      inner.forEach((num, idx) => {
        copied[idx].push(num)
      })
      return copied
      }, Array(arrayToReduce[0].length).fill([]))

    console.log(reduced)
```

Expected output: `[[1], [2], [3]]`

Actual output: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` isn't the culprit, it is `fill`.

You've created an array the same length as the original and then filled it with a value.

That value is an array.

The *same* array.

So when you push a value to `copied[0]` you get a reference to that array and put a value into it.

And when you push a value to `copied[1]` you get a reference to that **same** array and put another value into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let arr = [ [ 7, 3, 47 ] ]
    let reduced = arr.flat().map(e=>[e])
    console.log(reduced)
```

//output: [[7], [3], [47]]

if you want your Expected output : [[1], [2], [3]]

Simply return index instead of item in inner array

```
    let arr = [ [ 7, 3, 47 ] ]
    let reduced = arr.flat().map((e,i)=>[i+1])
    console.log(reduced)
```